# htaccess hotlink protected how to fix

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mp4

I am using .htaccess hotlink protected

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain1.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(mp4|avi|3gp)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

All my files save on domain1.com and use php script on domain2.com all file mp4 format

My problem is that when I try to download file from my domain2.com within my php script then the following error is shown

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access file.mp4 on this server.

what is wrong on that.how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either allow the HTTP Referer that is sent when requesting the resource from `domain2.com` (possibly `http://domain2.com`, but you may need to check the headers that are sent - there might not even be a `Referer` header sent). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(mp4|avi|3gp)$ - [NC,F]
```

Or, change the way you request the resource from `domain1.com` in your PHP code so that the appropriate `Referer` is sent with the request (ie. *faked*).

Note, however, that "hotlink" protection is not reliable and easily circumvented.

Comment: What does the `Referer` HTTP request header contain in the request for the resource from `domain1.com`?

Comment: mp4 file on domain1.com and send request from domain2.com php script.....htaccess file in domain1.com

Comment: How exactly are you requesting this file in your PHP script? Are you using CURL or simply using _file_get_contents()_ with an HTTP wrapper or something else?

Comment: i am using this code.this is workng only on mobile device when i try to download file from pc show error Forbidden .can you please tell me why not working on desktop?
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(Android|iPad|iPhone|\ Phone)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(mp4|jpg|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
` @mrwhite

Comment: "this is workng only on mobile device" - that code won't do anything on a mobile device/browser - which is why it's "working"! The first `RewriteCond` directive specifically excludes any mobile user agent, so the directive simply won't be processed and so a mobile device is _never_ blocked.

Comment: how can i do same thing on pc?i need download file on pc if i remove first `RewriteCond` user agent then show Forbidden error on both pc and mobile

Comment: To do the same thing on a PC you simply delete all those directives! As mentioned, on a mobile, those directives are not doing anything (literally _nothing_)! As mentioned in my answer, you need to find out what HTTP `Referer` is being sent on the request by analysing the HTTP request headers. But, as already mentioned, hotlink protection is not reliable and could well cause you additional problems - you need to be aware of these problems before you implement this.